# Handling one-to-many relationship with ZF partialLoop

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

Lets say i'm listing musical artists, each artist has basic information like Name, Age etc. stored in an artist table. They also have entries in an Albums table (album name/album cover etc), referencing the artist table using the artist id as a foreign key.

I have the Model_Artist (Artist.php) file:

```
class Model_Artist extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'artist';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('Model_ArtistAlbums');
    public function fetchArtistss()
    {
        $select = $this->select();
        return $this->fetchAll($select);
    }
}
```

and to the Model_ArtistAlbums (ArtistAlbums.php) file

```
class Model_ArtistAlbums extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'albums';

    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'Artists' => array(
            'columns'       => 'alb_art_id',
            'refTableClass' => 'Model_Artist',
            'refColumns'    => 'art_id'
        )
    );
    // etc
}
```

in my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    /* THIS WORKS
    $art = new Model_Artist();
    $artRowset = $art->find(1);
    $art1 = $artRowset->current();
    $artalbums = $art1->findDependentRowset('Model_ArtistAlbums');
    foreach($artalbums as $album){
        echo $album->alb_title."<br>";
    }
    */
    $arts = new Model_Artist();
    $this->view->artists = $arts->fetchArtists();
}
```

in the view file:

```
$this->partial()->setObjectKey('artist');
echo $this->partialLoop('admin/list-artists.phtml', $this->artists);
```

but with this code in artists/list-artists.phtml:

```
foreach($this->artist->findDependentRowset('albums') as $album):
// other stuff
endforeach;
```

i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   findDependentRowset() on a non-object

A `var_dump` of `$this->artist` = `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in you calling view:

```
<?php $this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('artist'); ?>
<?php echo $this->partialLoop('yourpartial.phtml', $artists); ?>
```

Note -  i beleive this changes the object key globally for the instance of the partialLoop helper so you might want to pick something more generic than `artist` or remember to reset it if you use partialLoop for something else later in the same view.

and in your partial:

```
<?php foreach($this->artist->findDependentRowSet('Albums') as $album): ?>
 <!-- looping stuff here -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Check the docs/api for Zend_Db_Table_Row for what the actual argument(s) to `findDependentRowset` should be in terms of your projects model naming conventions. You may also need to set some things up in your table class if you havent already defined the `_referenceMap`.

Comment: strange, at the moment i'm getting this error: "Message: Plugin by name 'FindDependentRowset' was not found in the registry"

Comment: oh ok $this must refer to the view instance, big "duh" on my part see edit.

Comment: pretty confused but powering through :). should it not be <?php echo $this->partialLoop('yourpartial.phtml', $this->artists); ?> ? otherwise i get a foreach error

Comment: absolutely correct. That was my mistake... AGAIN. i dont knwo whether im helping or hurting! ;-)

Comment: haha, you're definitely helping. thanks :)

right okay, that now gives me this:Fatal error: Call to a member function findDependentRowset() on a non-object - thrown by this line: foreach($this->artist->findDependentRowset. what is the string "artist" in ->setObjectKey('artist') referencing specifically? not sure where i'm going wrong.

Comment: `setObjectKey` should tell it to expose the iteration of whatever var youre passing in to `partialLoop` (ie `$this->artists`) as that property within the `partialLoop` view. so for example `$this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('model')` should expose the `$this->model` in each iteration of the view template in the loop.

Comment: ah, so the label itself in that context is not significant. it could just as well be:
$this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('foobar'); 
and that would make $this->foobar ?

Comment: Thats is my understanding :-)

Comment: just realised what it is, not sure if you changed it at some point or i just copied it wrong but i had $this->partial()->setObjectKey('artist') instead of $this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('artist');